# ASP.NET how to make OnRowDataBound event asynchronous?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I currently have a nested datagrid. The top-level grid gets data from a stored procedure. The nested grid gets data from a stored procedure based on the column value of each row.

Here is my ASPX code

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Async="true" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="CS" Debug="true" %> 

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
    * {
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;

    }
    </style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("[src*=plus]").live("click", function () {
        $(this).closest("tr").after("<tr><td></td><td colspan = '999'>" + $(this).next().html() + "</td></tr>")
        $(this).attr("src", "images/minus.png");
    });
    $("[src*=minus]").live("click", function () {
        $(this).attr("src", "images/plus.png");
        $(this).closest("tr").next().remove();
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:GridView ID="gvCustomers" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="Grid"
        DataKeyNames="ID" OnRowDataBound="OnRowDataBound">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <img alt = "" width="25px" style="cursor: pointer" src="images/plus.png" />
                    <asp:Panel ID="pnlOrders" runat="server" Style="display: none">
                        <asp:GridView ID="gvOrders" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass = "ChildGrid">
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="135px" DataField="Label" HeaderText="Label" />
                                <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="IDs" HeaderText="IDs" />

                                <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataFormatString="${0:###,###,###.00}" DataField="Total" HeaderText=Total" />
                            </Columns>
                        </asp:GridView>
                    </asp:Panel>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="Source" HeaderText="Source" />
            <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="Label" HeaderText="Label" />
            <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataFormatString="${0:###,###,###.00}" DataField="Total20" HeaderText="Total20" />
            <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataFormatString="${0:###,###,###.00}" DataField="Total1" HeaderText="Total1" />
            <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataFormatString="{0:P1}"  DataField="Average_Fee_PCT" HeaderText="Average Fee" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is C# code

```
using System; 
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

public partial class CS : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write("<script>console.log('Page Loaded');</script>");

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {

            gvCustomers.DataSource = GetData("exec ReturnData '" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "'");
            gvCustomers.DataBind();
        }
    }

    private static DataTable GetData(string query)
    {        
    

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=SQLSERVER;Initial Catalog=DBNAME;User Id=user;Password=pass"))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = query;
                using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
                {
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                    using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
                    {
                        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                        sda.Fill(dt);
                        return dt;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    protected void OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write("<script>console.log('Next Column...." + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff") + "');</script>");

        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            
            Response.Write("<script>console.log('Pulling data...." + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff") + "');</script>");

            string ID = gvCustomers.DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
            GridView gvOrders = e.Row.FindControl("gvOrders") as GridView;

            gvOrders.DataSource = GetData(string.Format("exec ReturnDataSingle '" + ID + "', '"+ DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "'"));

            gvOrders.DataBind();
            Response.Write("<script>console.log('Pulled data...." + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff") + "');</script>");

        }
    }
}
```

Currently, after each top-level row is created, it runs a stored procedure and returns the data as a nested gridview.

Each time the stored procedure runs for the nested grid view, it takes 200ms for it to return the data. The issue is that with 3 or 4 rows it is pretty fast. But when I have 300 rows, it will take 1 minute for the page to fully load.

Are there any ways I can change it so it won't wait until the current row is completed before moving onto the next row?

Comment: No you cannot make DataBound async, this is not how webforms work. You either need to use some sort of ajax call to an async webmethod or rethink your design so those nested calls are not needed (pehaps only show them on row expand with a separate ajax call)

Comment: I not looked close but is the nested grid expanded all the time? If one could add a expansion type UI, then you could only pulled the child data when the grid row is selected/expanded.  this would also mean you don't load up un-necessary data.